# can't find linkage dependency

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to compile my package but I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgripper_click_ui
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In my manifest I have the following two dependencies which possibly give me the hard time but it should be including the missing library:

```
<depend package="pr2_gripper_click"/>
<depend package="pr2_pick_and_place_demos"/>
```

This error occurs when I run make or rosmake. I am using diamondback.

Any clues?

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12419/can%27t-find-linkage-dependency/) by [Yianni](https://answers.ros.org/users/215/yianni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2011-12-30**:
How have you installed the pr2_object_manipulation stack? Which version of linux are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gripper_click_ui library should be in the pr2_gripper_click package.

Try running 'rosmake pr2_gripper_click'

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2011-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0